# Add labels on top of histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, histogram

I want to plot a histogram and label each bin by the average of some other variable.

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
meanwt=mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(meanwt = mean(wt)) %>% pull(meanwt)
g=
  ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=carb, y=..count..)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.3, position="identity", lwd=0.2,binwidth=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.7))
```

It works well when I plot the bin count

```
##plot the count of bin  
g+stat_count(aes(y=..count..,label=..count..),geom="text",vjust=-1)
```

[image]

However, If I want to label mean of some other variable then it doesnt work.

```
#plot mean of some other variable
g+stat_summary(aes(x=carb,y=wt),xfun.y = "mean", colour = "Black", size = 2, 
               geom = "text",position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25,label = meanwt)
```

[image]

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: It is probably a typo: xfun.y = "mean". should be: fun.y = "mean"

Comment: @ Aleksandr It did not solve the problem. I still have the same issue.

Comment: @user3978632: Aleksandr's fix works for me. You should restart your R session and try again

Comment: @Tung I restarted my system and tried again but the labels are not at top of the histogram. They are aligned towards the mid part of graph.

Comment: That's another issue, how to align your labels. See hjust and vjust properties.

Comment: @ Alekandr I have added the figures in the post. I want the labels to align at the top of each histogram for the second figure. Somehow the placement of lables are not at the top.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why Aleksandr's suggestion did not work. As an alternative, you could use this:

```
dat <- mtcars %>% select(carb, wt) %>%  
  group_by(carb) %>% mutate(mean_wt = mean(wt), carb_count = n()) 
g + geom_text(data=dat, aes(carb, carb_count+0.5, label=mean_wt), color="black", check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]

Based on Tung's suggestion!

Comment: Thanks, your labels are overlayed, some are dark and others are not.

Comment: You can add `check_overlap = TRUE` to `geom_text` to make the text labels look nicer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is good to know what you are dealing with and what you want to achieve. In this case you want to find how many cars have 1, 2, ... , 8 cylinders. So all you need to do is to group by cyl and find how many cars drops in that category:

```
mm <- mtcars %>% 
              group_by(carb) %>% 
              summarise(n = length(wt))
```

Next you may want to use simple bar chart to plot **cyl** against number of occurrences (**n**):

```
ggplot(data=mm, aes(x=carb, y=n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5, position=position_dodge(), fill = "steelblue") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=n), vjust=1.5, color="white",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=4)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(mm$carb), max(mm$carb), 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(mm$n), max(mm$n), 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I feel like answering my own question by combining help from @Aleksandr and @Prradep. I am not sure if this is super easy to read but for a newbie like me would help.

```
##reading the library and data
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

##aggregating the data (for some strange reason I have to use dplyr:: everytime I use a function within piping)
dat <- mtcars %>% dplyr::select(carb, wt) %>%  
  dplyr::group_by(carb) %>% dplyr::mutate(mean_wt = mean(wt), carb_count = n()) 

##plotting the data
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=carb, y=..count..)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.3, position="identity", lwd=0.2,binwidth=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.7))+
  geom_text(data=aggregate(mean_wt~carb+carb_count,dat,mean), aes(carb, carb_count+0.5, label=round(mean_wt,1)), color="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you happen to load `plyr` after `dplyr`? `plyr`'s functions will mask `dplyr`'s